# WPBakery Accordion Background Color

Tags: css, wordpress, accordion, background-color, visual-composer

I'm using WPBakery (version 5.4.7) Accordion section to display a Gravity Form. I'm trying to change the background color of the active accordion section to black.

Following different forum examples, I tried the following CSS to my themes Custom CSS area:

```
.vc_tta-color-black.vc_tta-style-classic .vc_tta-panel .vc_tta-panel-heading { background-color: #000000 !important;}
```

...but it's not working.

Any tips?

Thanks!

Comment: and what about only `.vc_tta-panel .vc_tta-panel-heading { background-color: #000000 !important;}` ?

Comment: Very hard to propose solution without seeing at least the output code. Can you share a link?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Your code managed to change the heading panel; but the background color inside the active accordion panel is still white, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.dima-accordion-inner {
  background: #ffffff;
}
```

This should do the trick. Just change the colour to what you want.